# Is the increased intraocular pressure from playing wind instruments damaging to the eye?

Tags: eye, lasting-effects-duration, opthalmology, glaucoma, intraocular-pressure-iop

People who play wind instruments often practice for hours every day. [Some studies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10647731) ([this one as well](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/49755064_Intraocular_pressure_fluctuations_in_professional_brass_and_woodwind_musicians_during_common_playing_conditions)) mentioned that intra-ocular pressure (IOP) raises during play. Some [other studies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10958606) measured a raise too but that was not that meaningful.

Increased intra-ocular pressure in conditions like [glaucoma can cause vision changes](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15610974), even permanent vision damage.

Can the increased IOP experienced during frequent playing of a wind instrument lead to eye damage, such as permanent vision changes?

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE! [For a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/8212), we can not, and will not, give personal medical advice. If you have a question regarding your personal health, you should see a doctor. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [ask] page and [meta]. I have voted to close this question and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question) explains question closure.

Comment: I would add that this question could be a legitimate question, but you need to remove all the personal details and not ask for speculation on the cause of your myopia.

Comment: Highly agree. The underlying premise is very interesting, and the references cited shows you did some work to try to answer this yourself, which we encourage here.  I edited the question accordingly to meet site guidelines and vote to keep open. If you disagree, feel free to revert.

Comment: I retracted my close vote due to @DoctorWhom's edit.